# How to add multiple dynamic WHERE queries?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, where-clause

I want to make a WHERE query with POST. A dynamic WHERE query is required when multiple query requests are received with POST.

I am using the [PDOx repo](https://github.com/izniburak/PDOx/blob/master/DOCS.md#where). I want to pull data with multiple `WHERE` queries, but how can I do this? If it is not possible with PDOx, how can the classical (without any DB class) connection be made?

Sample;

```
$db->table('test')->where('active', 1)->getAll();
# Output: "SELECT * FROM test WHERE active='1'"
```

Comment: Did you try ->where(...)->where(...)?

Comment: @Maksim Hi, This manual is an addition. What I'm talking about is dynamic. How about multiple where queries coming with POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple where() on query object:

```
$query = $db->table('test');
if($_POST['one']){
  $query->where('field', $_POST['one'])
}
$result = $query->getAll();
```